# I am facing issue while installing git plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(Unknown Source)
            at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
        Caused: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
            at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
            at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1139)
```

Giving error when trying to install jenkins plugin:

```
Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/3.6.0/git.hpi to C:\Users\GUR49249\.jenkins\plugins\git.jpi.tmp
```

Comment: I see you've already found a work around. However, please add some more content to your question. Throwing in a stack trace and an error is not a question that follows the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Following the guide will make it a better use for other users facing the same or a similar issue and helpful community members can be a better help for you. Updating your question even after your work around would be a benefit for the community.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this issue.We can download the required plugins and put them in the ./jenkins\plugins folder.After that we need to take restart of jenkins server.